# How to fix "Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access" Error even I know it is logged in

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am new to both Angular and Firebase. Here is my problem when I upload the image to Firebase Storage by using the following method. When I upload the image, the image, even the user appears to signed in, but console says that "Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access Object". I am wondering what should I do for this?

The code I use is the latest Angular, and Ionic for the library.
Before this, I have tried to modify the rules in Firebase Storage, however, all these attempts are failed

profile.page.ts:

```
export interface Image {
  id: string;
  image: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.page.scss'],

})

export class ProfilePage {

  public isPublic: boolean;

  validations_form: FormGroup;
  // matching_passwords_group: FormGroup;
  errorMessage: string = '';
  successMessage: string = '';



 url: any;
 newImage: Image = {
  id: this.afs.createId(), image: ''
 }
 loading: boolean = false;
 downloadURL: any;
  userEmail: string;
;


  uploadImage(event) {

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;


    console.log(user.email);

    this.loading = false;
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
      // For Preview Of Image
      reader.onload = (e:any) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
        this.url = e.target.result;

        // For Uploading Image To Firebase
        const fileraw = event.target.files[0];
        console.log(fileraw)


        const filePath = '/Style/' + user.uid + '/Image' + (Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000) + 1);
        const result = this.SaveImageRef(filePath, fileraw);
        const ref = result.ref;
        result.task.then(a => {
          ref.getDownloadURL().subscribe(a => {
            console.log(a);

            this.newImage.image = a;
            this.loading = false;

          });

          this.afs.collection("Style").doc(user.uid).set(this.newImage);

        });
      }, error => {
        alert("Error");
      }

    }

  }



  SaveImageRef(filePath, file) {

    return {
      task: this.afStorage.upload(filePath, file)
      , ref: this.afStorage.ref(filePath)
    };
  }
```

My security rule:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
           allow read, write,create,delete;
        }
       }
```

The expectation is the user is authorized and has the whole access to the Firebase Storage.

Comment: It is unclear if you are talking about Firestore, or Firebase storage -- your text and tags say firestore (the nosql database), but the error and code looks more like firebase storage (the blob storage).  Can you clarify?  Either way, you need to share your security rules ([for firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started), [for firebase storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start)).

Comment: It is FireStorage

Comment: The rule is here:

Comment: service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
           allow read, write,create,delete;
        }
       }

Comment: Your rules should certainly allow a write, so I don't see something obvious here, but there's a lot of code unrelated to the actual storage operation, and some code appears to be missing (for example, where `afStorage` is injected).  I recommend you create a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that could simplify debugging.  In particular, take a look at the very simple examples [in the AngularFire documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md).

Comment: Sure, I will edit it into a simplified code